# In a chapter*, how do I remove chapter numbers from figures and add the title to the running head?

Tags: sectioning, floats, header-footer, chapters

I have a document with numbered chapters. At the end I wanted to add some appendices without a number (only a title). I used this solution, which I found online:

```
\newcommand\chap[1]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
}
```

This works from a title and TOC perspective, but it still has two major issues:

- Figures still have a chapter number. So if my final chapter is chapter 10, figures i the appendix will be marked as 11.something. Can I get rid of the 11. and hide those figures from the index of figures?
- Running heads seem to ignore the appendix name. So all my appendixes have 'Bibliography' written in the head! Can I have the appendix (chapter*) title show up there, or perhaps a custom string?

Thanks for any help you may provide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are two questions, that I'll try to answer:

### Figure numbering

You can re-define the figure numbering macro, by saying

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
```

There's a package [`chngcntr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) that is capable of doing it by a special command, but there's no need to use it IMHO

### Running heads

You should add this line to your definition of `\chap`:

```
\markboth{#1}{#1}
```

### General remark

I think that in a document with numbered chapters, the appendix chapters should be marked by letter, as the typographical consensus suggests. To do so, just add this line before your first appendix:

```
\appendix
```

Comment: It's magic!

I had no idea that \appendix existed and no one I asked until now was capable of telling me. That seems to solve all my problems (for the future generations: The \chap command from my question is not necessary in this case).